# Reason and Impact of Displaying "All People" Link in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

In SharePoint 2007 there is a link "All People". This link is useful for site administrator to manage user in their site collection. However, in SharePoint 2010 this link is no longer available to user. A solution for this is found in http://snahta.blogspot.com/2010/08/all-people-link-missing-in-sharepoint.html

It seems like this link is hidden in SP2010. My question are:

1. Is there any reason that Microsoft hides "All People" link?
2. Is there any impact if we provide "All People" link to the user in SharePoint 2010?